# Don't print variable if it's zero

Tags: c++

```
double a, b, c, d, x, y;
char operation


cout << setw(6) << a << b 
     << setw(3) << operation
     << setw(6) << c << d 
     << " = "
     << setw(6) << x << y 
     << endl;
```

I'm making a calculator which takes two complex numbers and adds subtracts etc. My question is how do I format my output so that 0's are not displayed.

I.E. if the input is (a+bi)(c+di) the output is a+bi * c+di = x+yi But a, b, c, d, x, y are only displayed if they are nonzero.

I know I can do it with if statements and stuff but I was hoping there's a shorter, more efficient, path.

Comment: 10i * 7+17i = 70i+17i = 87i in ordinary mathematics. Are you sure you want a custom notation that deviates from all existing norms?

Comment: There are other ways, but `if` statements are the most straight-forward and easiest to understand.

Comment: I just threw that in as an example to show the output. I updated the problem so it's correct.

Comment: your complex arithmetic example is incorrect.

Comment: ... That edit makes no sense. For the input you give, (0+10i)(7+17i), your original result of -170+70i is correct. It's just the 10i * 7+17i representation of the input that's wrong, and that's the thing you left unchanged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can avoid doing the condition and printing if non-zero *somewhere*.

About all you can do is wrap it up so most code doesn't need to deal with it:

```
class complex { 
   double x;
   double i;
public:
    // ...

    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, complex const &c) { 
        // if both parts are 0, we probably want to print *something*
        if (c.x == 0.0 && c.i == 0.0)
            return os << 0;
        if (c.x != 0.0)
            os << c.x;
        if (c.i != 0.0)
            os << c.i << "i";
        return os;
     }
};

complex a, b, c;

// ...
cout << a << operation << b << " = " c << "\n";
```

You'll have to add a little more if you want this to honor (for example) width/precision correctly (though for real use, you undoubtedly want to use the `complex` class that's already in the standard library instead).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it by including `<complex>`

```
std::complex<double> com_one; // value 0 + 0i 
std::complex<double> com_two(3.14); // value 3.14 + 0i
std::complex<double> com_three(1.5, 3.14) // value 1.5 + 3.14i 
std::complex<double> com_four(com_two); // value is also 3.14 + 0i
```

Then to use arithmetic operations, you can just use

```
std::cout << com_one + com_two << std::endl; 
std::cout << com_one - 3.14 << std::endl; 
std::cout << 2.75 * com_two << std::endl; 
com_one += com_three / 2.0;
```

Source: http://stdcxx.apache.org/doc/stdlibug/20-2.html

For checking if it's a zero check it using `if`, and compare it with a zero. This is the most clean technique.